# How do you separate a javaScript variable's Whole number and it's decimal to style them separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If a non-whole number (decimal) integer is on a JS variable, what would you do to separate number and decimal so you can style them separately in CSS? Is there a magic JQuery/plugin/Library for that?

http://jsfiddle.net/vm7488/1ggbow5b/

(you can tell that a well-designed JSFiddle is seriously begging for an answer here)

Currently, push comes to shove - I'm planning to do a var modulus 1 not-equal to zero ( `varia % 1 != 0` ) conditional and workout something from that, but if there was something, something like a already-made, built in function to do that, that would be awesome help, thanks!

Comment: Keep it simple. Just split the string based on the decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the updated version of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/1ggbow5b/2/

```
function hey() {
    //generate 25.50 and simply display it.
    this.num = 25.50;
    var parts = this.num.toString().split('.');
    this.whole = parts[0];
    this.dec = Number("."+parts[1]).toFixed(2).replace('0','');  
    this.num = this.whole + this.dec;
}
```

Updated fiddle with comments : http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/1ggbow5b/4/

Comment: Wow, perfect! Although when you change the Number to 25.00, you'll get a 25^NaN value :)  I just had to change line 3 of the JS to `var genNum = 25.00;
    this.num = numeral(genNum).format('0.00[0]');`  Which fixed it, now it's perfect, thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 4):

You can just simple separate it by using `Math.floor()`:

```
var integerPart = Math.floor(varia);
var fraction = varia - integerPart;
```

Then format these as you wish.

If you also need negatives, you should use `Math.ceil()` in that case, so like this:

```
if (varia < 0) {
    var integerPart = Math.ceil(varia);
    var fraction = varia - integerPart; 
} else {
    // same as above
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it really simple like @TrueBlueAussie suggested.

```js
var out = document.getElementById('out'),
    text = '25.50',
    parts = text.split('.');

out.textContent = 'Integer part: ' + parts[0] + '\nDecimal part: ' + (parts[1] || 0);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: This is [slightly more efficient than my suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/v8t4vn24/1/), +1

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to do any Math really, you could just use RegEx to split the pence from the pound:

```
var RegEx = /([\d]+?)\.([\d]+)/g;
var Price = '25.50';
var StyledPrice = Price.replace(RegEx, '<div class="pound">$1</div><div class="dot">.</div><div class="pence">$2</div>');
$('div').html(StyledPrice);
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v8t4vn24/)

#### UPDATE

Xotic750's answer is better as it's slightly speedier: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v8t4vn24/1/)

Answer (score 0):

***In case of handling it as a numbe*r.**

var value= 25.50;

var integer = Math.floor ( value) ; // = 25
var decimal = value - integer ; // = .50

***Also incase of strings***

var numbers= value.toString().split('.');

then you can perform casting on the array index  positions. Like,

integer = parseInt(number[0]);
fraction = parseInt(number[1]);